# How to use jQuery/JavaScript to create a data structure on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, mongodb

I am trying to take form input values and put them into an array of objects that is then sent to MongoDB. The part I am struggling with is how to get an array within the objects (please see comment in code below).

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <h3>Main Input:<input type="textbox"></h3>
      <h4>Sub-input 1:<input type="textbox"></h4>
      <h4>Sub-input 2:<input type="textbox"></h4>
      <h4>Sub-input 3:<input type="textbox"></h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Main Input:<input type="textbox"></h3>
      <h4>Sub-input 1:<input type="textbox"></h4>
      <h4>Sub-input 2:<input type="textbox"></h4>
      <h4>Sub-input 3:<input type="textbox"></h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Main Input:<input type="textbox"></h3>
      <h4>Sub-input 1:<input type="textbox"></h4>
      <h4>Sub-input 2:<input type="textbox"></h4>
      <h4>Sub-input 3:<input type="textbox"></h4>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The data structure I want to create on submit, which will then be sent to MongoDB using `req.body`, should look like this:

```
[{
  mainInput: "User's main input",
  subInputs: ["User's sub input 1", "User's sub input 2", "User's sub input 3"]
}, {
  mainInput: "User's main input",
  subInputs: ["User's sub input 1", "User's sub input 2", "User's sub input 3"]
}, {
  mainInput: "User's main input",
  subInputs: ["User's sub input 1", "User's sub input 2", "User's sub input 3"]
}]
```

Here is the JavaScript and jQuery I am currently using with the part I need help with commented:

```
var allInputs = [];
//object constructor to put each "main input" and its "sub-inputs" into and object
function input(mainInput, subInputs){
  this.mainInput = mainInput;
  this.subInputs = subInputs;
};

$("button").click(function(event){
  //prevent form submit so data can be compiled:
  event.preventDefault();
  $("div h3").each(function(){
    var a = new input()
    a.mainInput = $(this).val();
    a.subInputs = "???"; //this is the part I am need help with. 
                         //It should be an array of the main input's sub-inputs.
    allInputs.push(a);
  });

  //check that all inputs are in array:
  alert(allInputs);

});
```

Note: I am using H3s and H4s here just because I found it easier to traverse with jQuery, but if there is a better or more more minimal way please let me know.

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKrKqv

Thank you in advance for any guidance, it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the approach you mentioned in your question:

1. First add some class selectors to your html, specifically `main` to your main input and `sub` to the sub-inputs
2. Then gather the data from the input fields, using 1 main loop to get the data from the main input and then a nested loop to get the data from the sub-inputs. Push this data to some variables so we can reference it later.
3. Before the main loop ends, we call `Input`constructor and pass in the data we have stored in the variables.

Heres an example [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWYpgx)

Here's the code:

**JS**

```
function Input(mainInput, subInput){
  this.mainInput = mainInput;
  this.subInput = subInput;
}    

$("button").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //Array of Input objects
  var inputArray = [];

  $(".main").each(function(){    
    var input = $('input', this).val();
    //Array of SubInput objects
    var arrayOfSubInputs = [];

    $(this).siblings().each(function() {
      var subInput = $(this).find('input').val();
      arrayOfSubInputs.push( subInput );      
    });
    //Now that our data is stored, we can call the constructors

    var input = new Input(input, arrayOfSubInputs);

    //Push the Input objects to the input array
    inputArray.push(input);
  });
    $('.results').empty();
  //Loop on each array index and append it to results as json
    $('.results').append(JSON.stringify(inputArray));
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div>
    <h3  class="main">Main Input:<input type="textbox"></h3>
    <h4  class="sub">Sub-input 1:<input type="textbox"></h4>
    <h4  class="sub">Sub-input 2:<input type="textbox"></h4>
    <h4 class="sub">Sub-input 3:<input type="textbox"></h4>
  </div>
     <div>
    <h3  class="main">Main Input:<input type="textbox"></h3>
    <h4  class="sub">Sub-input 1:<input type="textbox"></h4>
    <h4  class="sub">Sub-input 2:<input type="textbox"></h4>
    <h4 class="sub">Sub-input 3:<input type="textbox"></h4>
  </div>
    <div>
    <h3  class="main">Main Input:<input type="textbox"></h3>
    <h4  class="sub">Sub-input 1:<input type="textbox"></h4>
    <h4  class="sub">Sub-input 2:<input type="textbox"></h4>
    <h4 class="sub">Sub-input 3:<input type="textbox"></h4>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<aside><h3>Results:</h3>
  <code class="results"></code>
</aside>
```

And some css to make it pretty.

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  max-width: 35%;
  margin: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

code {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
button {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
input {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: op expecting array for `subInputs`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for pointing it out! It should be good now.

Answer (score 2):

As with any repeating html modules you can simplfy by using common classes on common elements. You are basically using tagnames to create classes for you but are then restricted by default css/behviors for those tags

```
<div class="data-row">
  Main Input: <input class="main" type="text">
  Sub-input 1:<input class="sub" type="text">
  Sub-input 2:<input class="sub" type="text">
  Sub-input 3:<input class="sub" type="text">
</div>
```

Using classes you can set up the inner html with any internal structure you want

Now you can iterate all *data rows* and map the data within each to your final array

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  // iterate outer containers and get values of inputs inside instances 
  var arr = $('.data-row').map(function() {
      var $row = $(this),
        mainVal = $row.find('input.main').val(),
        subArr = $row.find('input.sub').map(function() {
          return this.value
        }).get()
      // return object for each data-row
      return {
        mainInput: mainVal,
        subInputs: subArr
      };

  }).get();
  // send to server
  $.post(url, arr);
});
```

Comment: I really like this solution!